# RabbitMQ setUp Issue In windows

Tags: rabbitmq

I am beginner to RabbitMQ. For the first time I am trying to configure RabbitMQ in my windows machine.I followed the steps given on official site www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html.But the problem I am facing is when I run "services.msc" command, I am not able to see RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME .
What could be the issue?

Comment: I suggest to use the setup http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html. It install rabbitmq as service automatically.

Comment: @Gabriele If you could just let me know that is there any difference between RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME and RabbitMQ.Because I can see RabbitMQ in services contol panel.

Answer (score 0):

Shivangi,

When you say "I am not able to see RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME", does it mean you don't see the RabbitMQ service in the list of services ?
What I usually do when RabbitMQ service fails to install correctly, I use the *rabbitmq-service* script located in the "sbin" installation folder  and run the 2 following commands in a command prompt:

```
rabbitmq-service remove
rabbitmq-service install
```